# Why does FFT generate a jaggedy signal

Tags: fft

I have an application that fills a buffer from my computer's microphone and does an FFT. My objective is to figure out what frequencies are in the sample.

I've tested the application by whistling as well as by playing [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yQcXlvccCI) from my cellphone into my computer's mic (I've tried two different mics to be sure). What I expect (taking the absolute frequency) is a smooth Gaussian-like curve with a mean at the frequency of the incoming tone, but what I'm getting is this:

[image: Jagged Frequency Spectrum]

What is the cause for the jaggedness of the signal's frequency spectrum? And what technique can be used to reliably identify the main frequencies present in the signal while filtering out the unwanted bumps?

Comment: This is the [windowing effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Windowing), causing spectral leakage. The longer your window (=buffer), the higher the spectral resolution. You can trade off resolution and spectral leakage by using different [window functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#A_list_of_window_functions). Right now you're effectively using a rectangular window because you just fill a buffer of finite length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are seeing is a peak from sinusoid convolved with a spectrum of rectangular window [***sinc function***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function). That is due to property:

$$x(t)\star w(t) = X(f)\cdot W(f) $$

Where your signal $x(t)$ is a sinusoid with a spectrum being a Kronecker (Dirac) Delta function, $w(t)$ is a rectangular window function. In DFT by default we are using rectangular window (taking a time snippet of a signal). Please check out this paper for more info: [**A Comprehensive Window Tutorial**](http://www.sandv.com/downloads/0603gabe.pdf)

Comment: Just a small (but important) detail: it should be *Dirac* delta rather than Kronecker delta.

Comment: @MattL.: I had similar conversation years ago with some professor. Basically outcome was that in digital domain there is always Kronecker delta and for Analog domain Dirac's. Any thoughts about that?

Comment: @jojek, when you're writing $x(t)$ or $w(t)$, what first comes to mind is that you're in the continuous-time domain (sometimes "analog domain", for the anal-retentive like me, "analog" and "continuous-time" are not quite the same thing). also, i might suggest the circled asterisk $\circledast$ ("\circledast" in $\LaTeX$) for convolution. $\star$ is okay, i guess, but i thought it may have had other uses in mathematics.  one thing, for sure, is we need to get away from $*$ because we use it for simple multiplication in *any* programming language i am familiar with (and i don't know very many).

Comment: If you talk about the spectrum or DTFT, i.e. the Fourier transform of a discrete-time signal (not the DFT), then you have a Dirac delta function in the frequency domain, which is defined for a *continuous* frequency variable. For discrete arguments, i.e. in the time domain, or - for the DFT - also in the frequency domain, you would normally have the unit impulse $\delta[n]$, which can be written as a Kronecker delta $\delta_{n0}$ or sometimes $\delta_n$.

Comment: ... However, in the DSP literature (at least in stuff that I read), the Kronecker delta is not very commonly used. And, as pointed out by RBJ, using $t$ and $f$ seems to imply continuous variables. But even in discrete-time, the spectrum of a sinusoid can only be described by the Dirac delta function (which is actually no function but a distribution).

Comment: also (and i know this gets me into arguments at *comp.dsp* and possibly here), the DFT does **not** inherently window data with anything, rectangular or not.  the DFT *inherently* maps a periodic discrete-time sequence of numbers with period of length $N \in \mathbb{Z}$ to another periodic discrete-frequency sequence of the same period length $N$.  and the iDFT maps it back.  **windowing** is what happens when you yank out $N$ samples out of a longer set (or continuous stream) of data.  "that's my story and i'm sticking to it."

Comment: actually, @MattL., i think when you're in the discrete-whatever domain, the Kronecker delta appears about as commonly as does the Dirac delta in the continuous-whatever domain.  just an opinion though.  and we all know you're strictly correct about the Dirac delta not being a function (if $f(x)=g(x)$ almost everywhere, their integrals over the same range have to be equal and, if $\delta(t)$ were a "function", it and $g(t)=0$, would be equal almost everywhere, yet their integrals are different).  i like to think of $\delta(t)$ having finite width of 1 Planck Time and make all that crap go away.

Comment: in a Starbucks in Cambridge Mass (by the Trader Joes).  gonna go caroling now with some friends.  love to chat about Diracs and (sp)Rectal leakage and the like, but i gotta go.  L8r, r b-j

Comment: In practice, most people yank samples out of a longer stream so that a finite length DFT fits in computer or DSP memory.  Thus the inherent rectangular window... if you want to actually compute anything from the real world (e.g. the OP whistling) not synchronous rotational shaft sampled.